# How to get python to load right library (a .dylib, not .so.3 on OSX)

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, extractor

I'm using the `extractor` module in python 2.7 via `pip install extractor`.  I'm on OS X using homebrew, and I have previously run `homebrew install libextractor`.   This creates files with extensions .a and .dylib in /usr/local/lib.  (GNU libextractor)

Around line 36 of extractor.py, there's this code:

```
try:
   #loading shared object file
   libextractor = cdll.LoadLibrary('libextractor.so.3')
except OSError:
   libextractor = cdll.extractor
```

I'm getting `OSError: dlopen(extractor, 6): image not found` when trying to `import extractor` from a python shell.

This appears to be because I don't have a .so.3 file, and that's hardcoded in the module.  But the error is coming from the except block, not the try block.

Is this error due to hard-coding of libextractor.so.3, and if so, how can I tell python to load the right library?    I've tried replacing that value with various files (.a, .dylib) that do exist, with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

If it worked you should use ctype.CDLL("libextractor") and let ctypes figure out the right extension. Sadly OS-specific extension magic is not there.

`ctypes` offers `find_library` method, if that works, use it. sadly it relies on external programs, which means a runtime hit and breakage on small or weird systems.

[other projects went ahead and hardcoded extension](http://notmuchmail.org/pipermail/notmuch/2013/015424.html) based on os.uname(). do that if you have to.

P.S. except clause is some weird workaround, in fact `ctypes.cdll.foo` is equivalent to `ctypes.cdll.__getattr__("foo")` which is same as `ctypes.CDLL("foo")` which doesn't work without `lib-` or extension.

Comment: By going straight into the python shell, I tried import ctypes, then ctypes.CDLL("libextractor") - now it's a different error, saying that no suitable image was found.   Did find:  /usr/local/lib/libextractor: not a file.

Comment: better link to filename detection based on OS type: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Lib/ctypes/util.py

Comment: /usr/local/lib/libextractor is a symlink to /usr/local/Cellar/libextractor/1.3/lib/libextractor (a directory) which contains many .so's and .a's

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following these instructions:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libextractor/manual/html_node/Preparation.html

Comment: I've installed libextractor-1.3 via brew; this was successful, and the binary extract program seems to operate as expected.   For OSX, the instructions you linked basically just say to run ./configure; make; make install, which I believe brew already did.